# DLL export and interface for DLL in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, dllexport

I have two `Visual C++` projects (in Visual Studio 2008 environment) and one of them has to use the others classes and functionalities. So I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx) which is pretty understandable but I have one point that needs clarification.

So let's say first project is `ProjA` and the second one is `ProjB`. `ProjB` needs to use the classes and funcs. of `ProjA` as I told in beginning. But there must be only one interface between these two projects which is a simple object like this:

```
class A
{
public:
   void write(data);
   void read (data);
}
```

so this must be the interface class which `ProjB` has to use, but in `ProjA` after `write` function is called there are a lot of oprations are done in seperate cpp files and other classes and funcs...

So my question is do I need to use `dllexport` functionalities only for `class A` or do I have to use them in all the other class and function definitions which are used inside `ProjA` as well? And how to write the interface file?

Thanks indeed...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `dllexport` only for the `A` class, provided that the type of the `data` parameter is not another class defined in `ProjA`.

When a class is "exported", all the code for that class **is** ans **stays** in it's DLL. If the ProjB knows nothing else from the ProjA classes, it should works.

Be sure to keep the two Dlls in sync (build otions, type of C RunTime...)

Comment: Sorry I just noticed your answer, thanks. So as far as I understand I have to provide the definition of data as well?

Comment: @user2955554 If `data` is a class type, with it's own methods, used by code in `ProjB`, and if these methods are implemented in a ccp file compiled into `ProjA`, then you have to export the `data` class as well.